# Como saber que elementos (js, css) estão demorando mais para serem renderizados?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navegador-de-internet

Minha página tem demorado bastante para carregar (20~30 segundos), as vezes ela chega a travar o meu navegador durante esse processo (e não foi só comigo, outras pessoas já vieram reclamar disso). Fiz alguns testes de velocidade de carregamento e percebi que a maior parte do tempo é gasto com renderização (no `New Relic` isso fica bem explícito).

Como posso saber, então, que elementos especificamente estão demorando mais para serem renderizados pelo Browser? Acredito eu que a demora na renderização seja por causa de algum css ou js em específico, já que até pouco tempo atrás o site estava carregando em 10 segundos, mas fiz tantas alterações que já não tenho mais ideia de onde pode estar o problema.

Comment: Tens um link para a página que possas colocar aqui? o Código da página seria util também.

Comment: Se juntares mais informação ao o link que pedi ^ vais ter respostas mais completas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1ª Opção (Usando o navegador):

1. Tecle `F12` em seu navegador (`chrome` ou `firefox` presumo).
2. Clique na aba `Network`.
3. Acesse seu site.
4. Você verá o tempo de cada download de cada arquivo e a ordem de download.

> 2ª Opção (Usando o pagespeed da google):

1. Acesse [Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).
2. Cole o link para o seu site e mande analisar.
3. Será exibida uma lista de "Gargalos" que o carregamento de sua página pode estar tendo.
4. O google irá fornecer alguns matérias de ensino para que você resolva estes "Gargalos" e `JS`, `CSS` e `Imagens` compactados (caso não tenha feito).
5. Resolva os gargalos apontados e mande analisar novamente (pode detectar outros problemas ou indicar que você não conseguiu resolve-los).